# sbackup "unable to access remote destination"

Tags: ubuntu, backup

I'm trying to get sbackup on my ubuntu 11.04 system set up to back up to a network disk.  I can ftp to the location, and create/delete files.  But whenever I try to set up sbackup via the GUI, I get an error message (after a little bit) saying "Unable to access remote destination".

Can anyone suggest a log that I might be able to look at?  Or another way of debugging the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this question would be better suited for askubuntu.com, but let's see :-)

There is a documented [bug in sbackup](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/sbackup#Konfiguration), mentioned on the ubuntuusers wiki, requiring you to put some sort of regular expression in the "Exclude" tab. Might that be the problem?